# Unable to install 'gensim'

Tags: python-3.x, gensim

When I  try to install `gensim` through cmd prompt, it gives me following error:

> "ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError:
> [WinError 5] Access is denied:
> 'c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\**pycache**\cython.cpython-38.pyc'
> Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions. "

I'm unable to sort this issue, please help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open windows command prompt with administrative permissions (Right-click on `cmd` and choose Run as administrator option).

---

***or***

Try using the `--user` flag

Example :
`pip install gensim --user`